# Can UI elements be cached and ignore code instructions?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to show / hide ***the mobile icon (button)*** depending on the data in the model.

To display models to the user, I use the UICollectionView. A cell is a custom class that contains a model on the basis of which it is created.

Assigning a model, I immediately check its parameters and adjust the appearance of the cell.

**My case:**

If I have one cell with a button, then delete it and the model. Then I create a new model and a cell based on it, **without** a button.

And despite the fact that according to the logs, all conditions work and the information about the model and cell is displayed correctly - on the screen I see the wrong display. **I still see a button** that shouldn't be there.

**I just can’t understand what this can be connected with and what can I do in this situation?**

I attach my logs, code and screenshots below.

```
class VideoCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var model : VideoModel!{
        didSet {
            if let _ = model {

                if let _ = model.time {
                    timeLabel.text = model.time!.stringFromTimeInterval()
                } else {
                    timeLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("undefined", comment: "Время видео не определено")
                }

                Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > model.id = \(model.id)")
                Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > check storeLocal")

                if model.storeLocal {

                    Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > storeLocal = \(model.storeLocal)")

                    self.model.thumbnail = UIImage(contentsOfFile: model.thumbLink)
                    storeButton.isHidden = false

                    Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > storeButton.isHidden = false = \(storeButton.isHidden)")
                } else {
                    storeButton.isHidden = true

                    Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > storeLocal = \(model.storeLocal)")
                    Logger.Log("VideoCell model.didSet > storeButton.isHidden = true = \(storeButton.isHidden)")
                }


                updateThumbnail()
            }
        }
    }

    func updateThumbnail(){
        if let image = self.model?.thumbnail {
            self.thumbnail.image = image
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configureCell() {
        self.thumbnail.image = nil
        self.thumbnail.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        let kHeight: CGFloat = self.frame.height / 500
        let kWidth: CGFloat = self.frame.width / 500

        Logger.Log("VideoCell cell.configureCell > initialize storeButton")

        storeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        storeButton.backgroundColor = .clear
        storeButton.tintColor = Config.UIPreferences.Color2
        storeButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        storeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "mobile"), for: .normal)
        storeButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        storeButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 5, bottom: 15, right: 20)
        storeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(storeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        storeButton.isHidden = true
        self.addSubview(storeButton)

        Logger.Log("VideoCell cell.configureCell > storeButton.isHidden = \(storeButton.isHidden)")


        storeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            storeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (130 * kWidth)+10),
            storeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (130 * kHeight)+10),
            storeButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            storeButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor)
            ])
    }
}
```

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell", for: indexPath) as? VideoCell{

            cell.configureCell()
            cell.delegate = controller
            cell.model = videos[indexPath.item]
            if let _ = cell.model {
                controller.getThumbImage(video: cell.model!)
            }

            Logger.Log("Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.islocal = \(cell.model.storeLocal)")
            Logger.Log("Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.id = \(cell.model.id)")

            return cell
        }

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
```

**My log:**

```
2019-12-05 23:48:47.842 *** VideoCell cell.configureCell > initialize storeButton ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.844 *** VideoCell cell.configureCell > storeButton.isHidden = true ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.849 *** VideoCell model.didSet > model.id = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/228D4B45-9CBF-4EFF-9018-803871595521/Documents/localVideoStorage/05-12-2019/1575564524524.mp4 ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.851 *** VideoCell model.didSet > check storeLocal ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.855 *** VideoCell model.didSet > storeLocal = true ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.862 *** VideoCell model.didSet > storeButton.isHidden = false = false ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.865 *** Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.islocal = true ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:47.868 *** Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.id = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/228D4B45-9CBF-4EFF-9018-803871595521/Documents/localVideoStorage/05-12-2019/1575564524524.mp4 ***  


2019-12-05 23:48:51.739 *** Day vc.updateVideo > before setting self.video ***  
2019-12-05 23:48:51.747 *** Day vc.numberOfItemsInSection > videos.count = 0 ***  


2019-12-05 23:49:09.940 *** Player router.dismissCamera() > call dayvc.refresh() ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.114 *** Day vc.updateVideo > before setting self.video ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.120 *** Day vc.numberOfItemsInSection > videos.count = 1 ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.123 *** VideoCell cell.configureCell > initialize storeButton ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.127 *** VideoCell cell.configureCell > storeButton.isHidden = true ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.130 *** VideoCell model.didSet > model.id = 1QctoIFxhwhNRxzvo7ImJhHYUMbuDHrqXJv ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.133 *** VideoCell model.didSet > check storeLocal ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.136 *** VideoCell model.didSet > storeLocal = false ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.139 *** VideoCell model.didSet > storeButton.isHidden = true = true ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.143 *** Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.islocal = false ***  
2019-12-05 23:49:11.148 *** Day vc.cellForItemAt > cell.model.id = 1QctoIFxhwhNRxzvo7ImJhHYUMbuDHrqXJv ***
```

[image: First video (with legal button)]
[image: Second video (with illegal button)]
1st screen (with legal mobile button) and 2nd screen (with illegal mobile button)

Comment: If your `cell.model` is set to `nil`, none of your `didSet`'s code will run, because it's tucked inside a conditional binding that won't be satisfied. Not sure if that's the definitive source of your error, but it's something to look into.

Comment: You should use `prepareForReuse()` btw, rather than defining your own `configureCell` and manually calling it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

Comment: You are adding your `storeButton` when you need it,  it you don't remove it when you don't. Cells are reused. `configureCell` is called on a cell that already has a store button (that isn't hidden) you then add another store button and hide it, but the first is still visible. You wed to add the button once and then just modify its `hidden` property

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thnx, I added `override func prepareForReuse() {
        self.storeButton.isHidden = true
    }` and it works. But I did not understand how I can do without the `configureCell()` at all, because the method is called only when reusing it, and not when creating the cell for the first time.

@Paulw11 thnx too, I checked, it really led to the accumulation of subviews. I fixed it like this `storeButton.removeFromSuperview()` in `prepareForReuse() `